# Losing queue contents in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, scala, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ to communicate work between a master and a number of worker nodes.

The master kicks things off, seeding a value in the queue.  Workers read the queue, do stuff, and usually write more work items to the same queue for other workers.

Running 1 ea. of master/worker, I let things run for a bit then shut down the worker.  My expectation is that the queue size/contents in RabbitMQ would remain constant from whenever the worker stopped (workers are the only consumers).

Unfortunately I'm finding is that I lose my queue's contents moments after the worker terminates (connections/channels closed).  On a typical run I'll have 100+ items in the queue when I shut down my only worker/consumer.  **Moments later my queue length is 0. Anyone know why?**  At this point my master is still alive and doing nothing on the queue.

(Note that no change happened on rabbitmq-server...it's left running.)

My usage:

```
In Master:

    Declared:
        channel.queueDeclare("my_q", false, false, false, null)

    Written:
        channel.basicPublish("","my_q", null, "content".getBytes())



In Worker:

    Declared:
        channel.queueDeclare("my_q", false, false, false, null)
        channel.basicQos(1)
        val consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel)
        channel.basicConsume("my_q", false, consumer)

    Read:
        val delivery = consumer.nextDelivery()
        channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false)

    Write:
        channel.basicPublish("", "my_q", null, "content".getBytes())
```

Comment: My only guess is that when you shut down the consumer, it quickly reads the remaining items in the queue without processing them (maybe you are shutting down a processing thread, but the consumer is still called with each message and it simply drops it???). This is just a wild guess though. Try killing your consumer from the OS (instead of shutting it down "normally") and see if the messages still remain in the queue. If they do, maybe my theory is right :)

Comment: You can put `basicAck` adter `basicPublish` in Worker app and this should guarantee that the message is acked only after you process it

Comment: Since you're declaring the queue with immediate=false and autoDelete=false, and you're calling basicConsume with noAck=false, I would not expect the behavior you're seeing. Now, you are also declaring the queue with durable=false, so you're queued messages will not stick around after a server restart -- but since you've said that nothing has happened to the server, this shouldn't be an issue. Here is an experiment to try: with no workers consuming messages from the queue, try publishing some messages from the master, and see how long these messages stick around in the queue.

Comment: They stick around (of course so long as I don't reboot the server).  I'll try the basicAck recommendation but I'm also thinking there's something "grabby" about the QueueingConsumer.  Maybe during shutdown the thread its running in goes wild and it's trying to pull a bunch of data from the queue.  I'll have to try some kind of simple replacement.